# Unable to insert data in MongoDb using Node Js

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I am trying to insert data in MongoDb using NodeJs but before inserting data I want to check whether data is already available in database or not if data is not available then only it should insert data in MongoDb.

**Problem** - Whenever I am saving data even though it is not available in database it is always showing 
              response "User exists".

This is what I have done so far:

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const dotEnv = require('dotenv').config();
const MongoClient = require('mongodb').MongoClient;

const dburl = process.env.URL;

router.use(bodyParser.json());
router.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

router.post('/saveSalesperson',(req,res) => {

      var data = {

         email:req.body.username,
         password:req.body.password,
         type:req.body.type
      };

MongoClient.connect(dburl,{useNewUrlParser:true,UseUnifiedTopology:true},(err,client) => {

              if(err){
                console.log("Error",err);
              }
              else{

                client.db('Mydb').collection('Users').findOne({email:req.body.username},function(err,user){

                           if(err){
                            console.log("Error",err);
                           }
                           if(user){
                               res.send("User exists");
                           }
                            else{

                    let collection = client.db("Mydb").collection("Users");

                    collection.insertOne(data,(err,resp) => {

                           if(err){

                               console.log("Error:".red +err);

                           }  
                           else{

                               res.send("User created");
                           }

                     });

                   }
                });
              }
        });

   });

module.exports = router;
```

Someone please let me know what I am doing wrong.Any help would be appreciated.

**THANKS**

Comment: Please use this code  if(user == null) for user existing

Comment: You can use if(!user) to check if user is defined or not.